# gradient breaks in a ggplot stat_bin2d plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a 2d histogram created with `stat_bin2d` in the `ggplot2` package. I'd like to control both the number of breaks in the color gradient, as well as where those breaks are located. I'm sure I'm just overlooking something small, but I can't figure out how to control the breaks in the binning.

Example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)^2
y <- rnorm(100)^2
df <- data.frame(x,y)
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) 
p <- p + stat_bin2d(bins = 20)
p + scale_colour_gradient2(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

This produces:

[image]

This plot only has 3 breaks at `c(5,10,15)` despite my futile attempt to put breaks at `c(1,2,3,4,5,6))`

Any hints?

Comment: Your plot makes me want to play Atari.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le

Answer (score 20, accepted):

here is an example combining `cut` and `bin2d`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=cut(..count.., c(0,6,8,9,Inf))))
p <- p + stat_bin2d(bins = 20)
p + scale_fill_hue("count")
```

As there are many ways to make the breaks arbitrary, if you define clearly what you want, probably you can get a better answer.

[image]

Comment: I can't get a better answer than this. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I like the solution, but I wonder if there is a way to get the scale to be marked at the (0, 6, 8, 9, Inf) breakpoints rather than denote them by ranges.

Answer (score 13):

Me thinks you probably want the less talked about cousin of `scale_colour_gradient2()`, `scale_fill_gradient2()`

Using your data:

```
p + scale_fill_gradient2(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Also note the optional parameters `low`, `mid`, and `high` for additional controls.

[image]

Comment: The colours in the legend do not match those used on the plot.

Comment: @Gavin - hmm, good catch. It looks like the entire range of values is being plotted, and breaks are only shown where specified...a bit strange. I wonder if that's the intended action? Regardless, adding `limits = c(1,6)` seems to give more intuitive values for the legend to match what is actually plotted. There may be other alternatives as well, so this isn't meant to be exhaustive.

Comment: @Gavin @Chase - Setting `limits = c(1,6)` makes the legend colors match the plots (for me at least) but I confess I don't have an explanation.

Comment: Breaks are like axis tick marks. Changing them just changes the legend, it doesn't modify the scale in any way.

Comment: Also I doubt you really want gradient2 give that there's no natural midpoint.

Comment: Hadley, is there a way to change the scale?

Comment: @JDLong What part of scale do you want to change? If you tell a desired output, maybe I can tell something.

Comment: @kohske, I just want to make the breaks arbitrary. This example is, of course, just a simple illustration of the problem. An example would be to make 4 buckets: 1-6, 6-8, 8, >9.

Comment: @JD - you could always define your buckets previously with `cut` and then pass that as the aesthetic.

Comment: @chase, possibly because I don't use `ggplot` very much, but I don't know how to define the buckets with `cut` and pass that as an aesthetic. Sounds like the basis of a good answer thought!

Comment: @JD - looks like kohske picked up on my random musings and offered a pretty slick solution. I think he's leading you on the path to ggplot righteousness.